# ButtonBase.Click is missing in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have mainPage.xaml, and inside it a grid, and inside grid I have a canvas.

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded" ButtonBase.Click="Grid_ButtonClick">
    <Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Margin="12,52,98,26" />
</Grid>
```

I have some user controls UC1, UC2, UC3 so on, which generate many buttons depending upon the game level. I fill the content of the button with a list value which is in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private List<int> _listofValues = new List<int>();
```

Because the functionality of all the buttons is the same, I want to handle the button click in the parent control, either in the grid or in the canvas.

I can do that in normal WPF apps. The first code 
`ButtonBase.Click="Grid_ButtonClick"`
But I can not do that in Windows Phone 8 applications. It's giving a compile time error.

Any idea how do I achieve the buttonBase.click event in Windows phone?

Comment: first I need to see the error

Comment: I have a grid <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" ButtonBase.Click="button_Click" > and the error i am getting is "the local property "Click" can only be applied to types that are derived from "ButtonBase""

Comment: it should read that the method you are using is depricated. Anyway I answered it below.

Comment: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/mobile/9780133383959/receiving-input-with-buttons/ch05lev2sec3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a parent UI Element handle the button clicks you can use a GestureService

This allows you to have complete control over your buttons as they are dynamically created. Within the Geasture Listener event you can handle each one based on the sender.

```
var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(your_newButton);

gl.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(GestureListener_Tap);
```

Then as you register them or after they are all done you can handle them all here.

```
private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Button theSendingButton = (sender as Button);
    //Handle your ish here
}
```

Reference and complete example [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-add-gestureservice-and-gesture-event-handlers-in-code-behind)

Comment: ok but what will be the way, if I create all the buttons first in the usercontrol, and then I load usercontrol to the `gamecanvas.children.add(uc1);`, so in this way how do I handle all the buttons click. All Buttons click actually the same task so only one code for the handling the click event is sufficient, only I will check `Sender as Button`